# Not able to access PubNub on Node-Red

Tags: node.js, iot, pubnub, node-red

[image]
After installing Node-Red and PubNub thorugh NPM Local, I am not able to find PubNub on Node-Red.

Kindly Help.

Comment: Node Red is not exactly a supported platform, but what exactly do you mean by *not able to find*?

Comment: When I run this command , npm install node-red-contrib-pubnub I should be getting PubNub input (subscribe) and output (publish) nodes for Node-RED. I am not able to find those nodes after I install.

Comment: Hang tight - we are cutting a new version that supports our v4 SDK.

Comment: [PubNub node-red module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-pubnub) has been updated.